# why mutableSet does not update !! for item in list in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, mutablelist

i want have setList of 1 to 10 but "currentNumber" (an item of list) can not toNext!!

```
var numList = mutableSetOf(1)
for (currentNumber in numList) {

    var temp = currentNumber
    temp++

    numList.add(temp)
    if (currentNumber == 10)
        break
}

println(" final List 0 to 10 $numList")
```

Comment: In addition to the other issues, calling a set ‘<something>List’ is just storing up trouble…

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are modifying the set whilst iterating through it.

You can create a sequence of number using the [rangeTo](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/range-to.html) operator as follows:

`1..100` creates an `IntRange` which you can convert to list or set.

Comment: Probably worth giving an example including the brackets: `(1..100).toList()`